# iPhone programming, loading plist data, access it

Tags: ios, iphone, search, sdk, plist

I have a plist in the following form:

Root (array)---> item 1 (dictionary) ----> Sch (string)
                                     ---> Name (string)
                                     ----> price (number)
         ----> item 2 (dictionary)----> .....same as item 1

How can I access each row (item1 to ...) and the its child (Sch, Name etc.)? One at a time?

I use:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
```

to load the file. How should I go about accessing each child?

What I am trying to do is, I have a NSString *message, what I want to do is to search the whole plist for matching string and display the whole item 1. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize a collection from a plist, the type is the root level object. Therefore you would not initialize a dictionary but an array like so:

```
NSArray *plistData = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
```

Then you would access it like this:

```
NSString *sch; 
NSString *name;
NSString *price;
for (NSDictionary *aDict in plistData) {
    sch = [aDict objectAtKey:"Sch"];
    name = [aDict objectAtKey:"Name"];
    price = [aDict objectAtKey:"price"];
    //.. do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911688/setting-up-a-plist-to-store-application-data-not-settings-for-an-iphone-game) is a link to a discussion that provided a very good example of how to access your data and which type of storage schemes would be more beneficial under certain circumstances.   @TechZen's solution is on target, I just thought this question would add an additional resource.  Hope this helps!