# How to call a web service only once for each table UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application which lists some states (e.g Assam, Andhra, Pradesh etc). When a state is selected, the next view show hospitals located in that particular state in a table view. The hospital names are loaded from a database using web service. This is done so far, no worries.

My problem is: Suppose I have listed hospitals for a state. I go back and select the same state again, the web service is called again and user has to wait for the data. So this is not a good idea. I don't want to call the web service again if I select the same state. How to store data and display it if state selection is same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your data in `NSUserDefault`

```
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:hospitalAry forKey:@"Hospital"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` as the `cachePolicy` of `NSURLRequest`.

As Apple stated:

> NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad Specifies that the existing cache
>   data should be used to satisfy a URL load request, regardless of its
>   age or expiration date. However, if there is no existing data in the
>   cache corresponding to a URL load request, the URL is loaded from the
>   origin source.

Answer (score 0):

to a void  calling web service each time , put the result you get from WS in an 2D NSMutableArray attribute of the  AppDelegate ,
 and each time the user select a state 
,verify if the array corresponding to your state is nil

Comment: it mean NSMutableArray inside an NSMutableArray the first one for the stats and the other for the hospitals

Answer (score 0):

Also SQLite/CoreData may be an approach you might want to consider storing data for a longer and permanent basis.

If currentDate != serverLastUpdatedDate then you can download data from server, you can store data in the form a plist for each rowtext for a quicker implementation. Have a look at the below ways of implementing it.

**plist**
[Setting up a plist to store application data (not settings) for an iPhone game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911688/setting-up-a-plist-to-store-application-data-not-settings-for-an-iphone-game)

**SQLite**
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application

**CoreData**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html